# New 2.4ghz keyboard from Amazon is showing up on network scan as a game system. MAC search reveals nothing

Tags: windows-10, networking, keyboard, steam-deck

I have a TECURS WK007 wireless keyboard (Made in China). MAC address is:

```
B4:8C:9D:7D:65:1B
```

Network scan with Fing from my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.

I am suprised it was on the network. But even more so as it showed up as a Valve Steam Deck. I use Steam but not on the system the keyboard was connected to at the time and that system was powered down.

Why would my keyboard need to be on my network and why is it disguised as a game system? The systems I use for Steam don't even show up as Steam.

Also, when I do a Mac search I get nothing.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your MAC address is "AzureWave Technology Inc." as per [Home | MAC Vendor Lookup Tool & API | MACVendors.com](https://macvendors.com/)

Comment: https://forum.glasswire.com/t/what-is-the-azurewave-technology-device-on-my-network-is-it-safe/11276

Comment: Thanks. I withdraw my question.